# MD5 hash decoding website which displays progress using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, progress

I'm creating a website which tries to decode md5 hashes (up to 5 chars).

Users can enter the MD5 hash they wish to decode and the website first checks whether the hash already is in the database.

Website: http://webtools.pieterhordijk.com

Hash in db: fbade9e36a3f36d3d676c1b808451dd7

Hash not in db: any other string of chars

If the hash isn't in the database yet the website will try to decode it.

What I would like to do is make an AJAX call to check if the hash is in the db. If not I want to display a progress counter while it is being decoded on the backend (PHP).

The code I currently have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form.decode').submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var submit_button = $('input[name="submit"]', this);
    var submit_image = $(submit_button).attr('src');
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $('table.result tr').remove();

    var html = '';
    html+= '<tr>\n';
    html+= '  <td><img src="/style/information.png" alt="Information" title="Finding value"></td>\n';
    html+= '  <td>'+$('input[name="hash"]', form).val()+'</td>\n';
    html+= '</tr>\n';
    $('table.result').append(html);

    $(submit_button).attr('src', 'style/ajax-loader.gif');

    $.ajax({
      url: action+'/json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: ({hash : $('input[name="hash"]', form).val() }),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data)
      {
        if (!data.result) {
          var html = '';
          html+= '<tr>\n';
          html+= '  <td><img src="/style/error.png" alt="Error" title="Hash not found in database"></td>\n';
          html+= '  <td>Couldn\'t find hash-value in our database!</td>\n';
          html+= '</tr>\n';
          html+= '<tr>\n';
          html+= '  <td><img src="/style/information.png" alt="Information" title="Decoding"></td>\n';
          html+= '  <td>Decoding hash (<span class="progress">0</span>%)</td>\n';
          html+= '</tr>\n';

          $('table.result').append(html);
        } else {
          var html = '';
          html+= '<tr>\n';
          html+= '  <td><img src="/style/accept.png" alt="Success" title="Decoded hash"></td>\n';
          html+= '  <td>'+data.value+'</td>\n';
          html+= '</tr>\n';

          $('table.result').append(html);
          $(submit_button).attr('src', submit_image);
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

The code too long to read? -> I just make a AJAX call to see if hash exists and if it doens't exist I add a row to the results table with the progress of the decoding process (default 0%).

What do I need to do from here?

I was thinking:

If hash doesn't exist run a js-function which calls (AJAX) a background script which starts the decoding progress.

The background process keeps track of it's progress by updating the db each x seconds (primary_key is hash).

The js-function which calls the background process calls another function which (AJAX) requests the progress every x seconds from the server until 100%

However before I start working this out I want to know whether this is the way to do it or perhaps there is a way smarter way of doing this.

Comment: How exactly do you intend to 'decode' a hash?

Comment: @Tomas: I was thinking brute-forcing it

Comment: Be prepared for a loooong wait. MD5, albeit not being the most secure hash algorithm, is a cryptographically secure hash algorithm. It would take you years with hundreds of machines to find an input for a given hash.

Comment: @JB Nizet: It tries values up to 5 chars. Let's say I have 100 possible chars. Will trying 10,000,000,000 possible values using a decent gfx card really take so long?

Comment: Brute-forcing which input values? There's a practically infinite number of possibilities.

Comment: @duskwuff: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789``-=~!@#$%^&*()_+,./<>?;:[]{}\|`

Comment: @JB Nizet Actually, brute-forcing an MD5 is a LOT faster than it used to be, due to graphics cards which can run insane numbers of parallel operations. For example, Whitepixel 2.0 reports a guess rate of 33.1 *billion* MD5 guesses *per second* on a rig with four HD 5970 graphics cards. Since the questioner is limiting the service to just 5 characters, it could probably be done in under 30 seconds.
 See: http://blog.zorinaq.com/?e=43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Instead of trying to brute force a hash*,

- wouldn't it make more sense to download a [rainbow table](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html)

Then have your program **simply check the [rainbow table](http://www.freerainbowtables.com/) (which you could store in SQL)** instead of having to brute force every previously uncracked hash.

Should the hash *not* be in the rainbow table, that means that it is huge/not easy to breack and should not be attempted to be cracked by the website at risk of using too much CPU and crashing your site.

Comment: Is the data available somewhere through an API? Otherwise I have to copy the new databases every x weeks.